# Getting types of another types properties in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types

Given this type:

```
type Foo = {
   Prop1: Bar1,
   Prop2: Bar2
}
```

From this type I want to extract a union type equivalent to:

```
type NewType = Bar1 | Bar2;
```

Can this be done in TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of [Keyof Type Operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html) and [Indexed Access Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html)

```ts
type NewType = Foo[keyof Foo];
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=31&pln=14&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgJwIxQLxQN4CgpTgLigDsBXAWwCMIEBuLAXyy1ElkQCY1McoLDTK1Oo2bhoAMQD2krtlxQACgklgkheMgA0PRcrDt1HBkxbQAchADuAFTFcpkgNoBrCCEkAzKA4C6NIA)